# Point-wise convergence cannot be normed

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set. Consider the space $\mathbb{C}^X$ of all functions $X\to \mathbb{C}$. For each $x\in X$ we build a seminorm $||\cdot||_x$ such that $||f||_x=|f(x)|$. I would like to prove that $\mathbb{C}^{X}$ endowed with this family of seminorms cannot be normed, that is there is no norm $||\cdot||$ such that $||f_n||\to 0$ if and only if $|f_n(x)|\to 0$ for all $x$.
Of course I mean the case when $X$ is infinite: if $X=\{1,2\ldots n\}$ then pointwise convergence is a usual convergence in any norm. However, what about the case of infinite $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that a neighborhood base for $f \equiv 0$ in the pointwise topology is given by

$$\left\{\bigcap_{x \in I} \phi_x^{-1}((-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)) \,\,\middle|\,\, \varepsilon > 0, I \subset X \text{ finite} \right\},$$
where $\phi_x(g) = g(x)$.

Use that to show that $f \equiv 0$ has no countable neighborhood base.

If the topology was normable, $f \equiv 0$ would have a countable neighborhood base.

EDIT: The above only works if $X$ is uncountable. Otherwise, instead show that $f \equiv 0$ has no bounded neighborhood.

Here, a set $X \subset C(X)$ is called bounded (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_%28topological_vector_space%29 ) if for every neighborhood $U \subset C(X)$ we have $X \subset r \cdot U$ for $r>0$ large enough.

EDIT: Also note the statement

> A locally convex space is seminormable if and only if there exists a bounded neighbourhood of zero.

on Wikipedia.

As the pointwise convergence is induced by the family of seminorms $|\phi_x|$, this is the reason why the topology is not normable.